# SSRS Report Data Source for Query with Multiple Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset that pulls from multiple databases on the same server. Historically (without doing research) in this case I would set the data source to ReportServer (the database that houses the execution log for the server, ect.) and noticed the dataset doesn't seem to care what the data source is.

I did a few hours of digging and couldn't find an answer. When using (or in my case, unioning) multiple data bases in a dataset, what should the dataset data source be in Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: what database do you connect and get this query running without any problem? use the same.

Comment: The query is connecting to multiple databases in table name. When writing queries in SQL Server, I experience the same issue where the data source appears to be ignored.

Comment: Did you try to execute your Query in The SSMS? if so tell me whats the result or ERROR message? please that can make some understanding.

Comment: The results in SSMS is the result of the query, there is no error. It just appears the data source in both SSMS and Visual Studio is ignored because the data source is in the table name. Based on the below answer this now makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying the database in the connection string sets the starting, default database for the query. If your permissions are adequate, then there is nothing to stop you from accessing other databases.

The database in the connection string will give your query the context that is used when you don't specify a database name as part of a table. If your query is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM vw_Interactions
```

then this will run against the database specified in your connection string.

For your case, when using a table with the same name across multiple databases, the default database doesn't matter much, as long as the data access account has permissions that let the query work.

Comment: Jamie, in the case of using unions that are cross-database I would conclude then that including the database name in the table is the best approach?

Will Visual Studio ignore the set data source, or will it hinder performance passing through two data sources?